# c# linq join on same table on null columns

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to LINQ query to get a description from the same table.

My table has
`id` as `int`,
`description` as `string`, and
`father` as `Nullable<int>`

`father` should hold the id, if the level has parent. For example:

```
id = 1, description = "box 1", and father = null 
id = 2, description = "box 2", and father = null 
id = 3, description = "box 3", and father = 2 
id = 4, description = "box 4", and father = 2
```

This says that id 2 has as children 3 and 4.

I'm trying to do LINQ to get the description of the father, but I get an "object that accepts null must have a value" error.

I was trying with:

```
var joined = (from item1 in lst
join item2 in lst on new { lvl = item1.father } equals new { lvl = item2.id }
select new {
item1.id,
item1.description,
item1.father,
father_description = item2.description
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If Id is an integer use int? which will accept the nulls.

Comment: the father is the one that accepts null, i can use item1.father.value but that fails as well

Comment: You do not need NEW : join item2 in lst on item1.father equals item2.id.  Make both null by using int?.

Answer (score 0):

`equals` means that you have to put values for comparison. Instead of that you are trying to compare bool expressions.

```cs
var joined = 
    from item1 in lst
    join item2 in lst on new { Id = item1.father.Value } equals new { Id = item2.id }
    select new 
    {
        item1.id,
        item1.description,
        item1.father,
        father_description = item2.description
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand why you're doing `equal` on new anonymous type.

Did you try this (works with latest C# 9) on the join:

```
join item2 in lst on item1.father equals item2.id
```

or

```
join item2 in lst on item1.father equals (int?) item2.id
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/handle-null-values-in-query-expressions